# Не могу связать две таблицы - ошибка "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, foreign-key

В первой таблице стараюсь связать две другие по `id`, но получаю ошибку:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

Из-за чего возникает данная ошибка ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gregs_list`.`Book_Author` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `book-id` INT NOT NULL,
  `author-id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gregs_list`.`Books` (
  `id` INT not NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `published` DATE NULL,
  `genre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `rating` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `kniga`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `gregs_list`.`Book_Author` (`book-id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gregs_list`.`Authors` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `born` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `gregs_list`.`Book_Author` (`author-id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: @RuslanSemenov обновил. Третий запрос просто удалили при правке

Answer (score 1):

У вас отсутствуют индексы полей `book-id` и `author-id`.
Измените первый запрос, добавив в него создание индексов:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gregs_list`.`Book_Author` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `book-id` INT NOT NULL,
  `author-id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  INDEX `book-id` (`book-id`),
  INDEX `author-id` (`author-id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, текст ошибки связанный с созданием `foreign key` в `mysql` довольно бесполезен. (может быть в 8.0 ситуацию улучшили, не проверял)

Точное описание ошибки возможно найти в несколько неожиданном месте - необходимо запросить [статус](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engine.html) `storage engine`:

```
show engine innodb status;
```

Затем в полученном тексте найти раздел `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`, где будет нормальное описание ошибки и некоторые пояснения. В этом случае примерно вот такое сообщение (это с моего тестового mysql 5.5)

> ### LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 181001 10:16:25 Error in foreign key constraint of table gregs_list/Books:
>
> ```
> FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
> REFERENCES `gregs_list`.`Book_Author` (`book-id`)
> ON DELETE NO ACTION
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB:
> ```
>
> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first
>   columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not
>   match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and
>   SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns
>   in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

В той таблице, на которую ссылаемся должны быть индексы по полям, на которые ссылаемся. Mysql отходит здесь от стандарта и достаточно любого индекса, а не только уникального, как предписывает стандарт. Но индекс должен быть создан явно пользователем. На таблице, которая ссылается, индекс будет создан автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

Внешний ключ ставится на дочернюю таблицу, а не родительскую как у вас. [Вот](https://webew.ru/posts/219.webew) хорошее описание внешних ключей на русском.

P.S. Почитайте на тему индексов в целом. Конструкции вида

> PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC)

некорректны.